# App crashes immediately when running on Android device but fine on Android simulator and iOS

Tags: react-native

The app crashes immediately only when opened on device. It runs fine on a Genymotion simulator but when running it on a Note 2 and a galaxy S7 it crashes immediately. Logcat shows this error:

`com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's`render`method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded`

I've removed all duplicate imports in `MainApplication.java`, I've tried upgrading react to 0.40, running `watchman watch-del-all`, deleting the `node_modules` folder, and running `npm cache clean` but nothing seems to help

**EDIT**

<del>I just created a new project and I'm getting the same error on device. What could be causing this?</del>
Never mind, I deleted the app on the device and reinstalled and now the new project opens fine.

Here's my `package.json`:

`"name": "DineSafe",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "parse": "1.9",
    "parse-react": "^0.5.2",
    "react": "15.4.0",
    "react-native": "^0.40.0",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-cacheable-image": "^1.4.3",
    "react-native-global-props": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "4.4.0",
    "react-native-triangle": "0.0.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "17.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "jest": "17.0.3",
    "jest-react-native": "17.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.3.2"
  }`

Comment: can you please share the code

Comment: where you define ref in your app code

Comment: which are the third party lib did you add?

Comment: I've used refs in quite a few places but its always in the render function. And if this was an issue, wouldn't it show up on the Android simulator and iOS devices as well? I'm adding my `package.json` file to the question

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I got it working by creating a new project and copying all my files into it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it where your problem stems from. Sometimes, when you install third party APPs, those third party APPs reinstall react in your project and those duplicate versions are causing this error.

According to your `package.json` you are implementing some lib that works fine in a simulator or emulator, but crashes when running the APP on a device.

**Solution:** go to the `node_module` folder of every third party APP that you have installed and search for react. After that, remove that lib by using the `npm uninstall lib_name` command and run the project.

Comment: I've checked every third party dependency in the `node_modules` folder. Have any other ideas I can try? I've been tearing my hair out over this

Comment: I just created an empty project and I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was accidentally deleted my com/.../MainActivity.java & com/.../MainApplication.java :D

Once i added them back, it runs well